# ServiceStack don`t save session cookies after login request form cross domen

Tags: angularjs, cookies, cross-domain, servicestack

I have a backend and angularjs on the client, they will work on different domains.
I set up the cors as follows:

```
Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(
                allowCredentials: true,
                allowOriginWhitelist: new[]{"http://localhost:11104", "http://localhost:61923/"},
                allowedMethods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
                allowedHeaders: "Content-Type"));
```

When I make a request to get cookies but they are not transmitted the following query therefore does not pass authorization.

Login request:

```
 $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:61923/auth/Credentials?format=json",
                params: { "username": $scope.LoginParams.UserName, "password": $scope.LoginParams.Password }
            })
```

[image]

Next request:

```
$http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:61923/IsAdmin?format=json"
            })
```

[image]

Help please, what am I doing wrong? ((
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include cookies in your http request by specifying `withCredentials`, e.g:

```
$http({
   method: "POST",
   url: "http://localhost:61923/auth/credentials",
   params: { "username": $scope.LoginParams.UserName, "password": $scope.LoginParams.Password },
   withCredentials: true
})
```